# Output JSON array append additional element PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops

I'm pretty sure I'm quite close so hopefully quick answer.

I'm able to generate this JSON:

```
apps: [
    {
        0: {
            PublisherCount: "7"
    },
        Id: "87",
        AppName: "Productivity, Focus, Habits & Life Success by Audiojoy",
        AppBundle: "productivitymind"
    }
]
```

But I'm trying to get to:

```
apps: [
    {
        Id: "87",
        AppName: "Productivity, Focus, Habits & Life Success by Audiojoy",
        AppBundle: "productivitymind",
        PublisherCount: "7"
    }
]
```

Here is my output loop (I think the issue is in the 5th row where I array_push the new value for `PublisherCount`. It creates an additional node instead of adding it to the end.

```
$temp_array = array();
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($publisher_apps)) {
$temp_array[] = $row;
$temp_array[$i][] = fetch_all(get_publisher_count_by_app_id($row['Id']))[0];
$i++;
}

$publisher_apps = $temp_array;

$result = array("apps"=>$publisher_apps);

output_json($result);
```

Thanks.

Comment: hum, try `$temp_array[$i]['PublisherCount'] = fetch_all(get_publisher_count_by_app_id($row['Id']))[0]['PublisherCount'];` (and indent your code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have rows like this:

```
['Id' => "87",
 'AppName' => "Productivity, Focus, Habits & Life Success by Audiojoy",
 'AppBundle' => "productivitymind"]
```

and `fetch_all(get_publisher_count_by_app_id($row['Id']))[0]` returns an array like this:

```
['PublisherCount' => 7]
```

so when you append it with `$temp_array[$i][]`, the entire array gets assigned to the `0` key of `$temp_array[$i]`.

There are various different ways you could get just the `PublisherCount` value. One way is to use `array_merge` to combine the result of `get_publisher_count_by_app_id` with `$row`, and then add the modified `$row` to your main array.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($publisher_apps)) {
    $count = fetch_all(get_publisher_count_by_app_id($row['Id']))[0];
    $temp_array[] = array_merge($row, $count);
}
```

If you do it this way, `$i` should become unneccessary.

Comment: Yup! @Dont' Panic that worked. Thank you. Makes sense, i kept getting a separate key for it.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
$temp_array = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($publisher_apps)) {
  $row['PublisherCount'] = fetch_all(get_publisher_count_by_app_id($row['Id']))[0]['Pub‌​lisherCount'];
  $temp_array[] = $row;
}

$publisher_apps = $temp_array;

$result = array("apps"=>$publisher_apps);

output_json($result);
```

Comment: this results in this:

    apps: [
        {
           Id: "87",
           AppName: "Productivity, Focus, Habits & Life Success by Audiojoy",
           AppBundle: "productivitymind",
        },
    { 
           PublisherCount: {
               PublisherCount: "12"
           }
    }
    ]

Comment: My bad, I've updated my answer. Please the updated code instead. However, after you get it working, rather than using a "fetch_all" function you should be looking to use a "fetch_one" or "fetch_first" kind of function, if one exists in your codebase, for performance purposes.